# How to solve $(y-x)dx+(x+y)dy=0$ with given condition $y(0)=1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was dealing with the question.

One of the point which line on the solution curve of the differential equation $(y-x)dx+(x+y)dy=0$ with given condition $y(0)=1$ is

(a) $(1,-2)$

(b) $(2,-1)$

(c) $(2,1)$

(d) $(-1,2)$

I rearranged the equation as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ and then using $y=vx$ I am getting $x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1-2v-v^2}{1+v}$.

I tried further as

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} x\frac{dv}{dx}&=\frac{1-2v-v^2}{1+v} \\\\ x\frac{dv}{dx}&=-\frac{v^2+2v-1}{1+v}\\\\&=-\frac{v^2+2v-1+2-2}{1+v}\\\\&=-\frac{v^2+2v+1-2}{1+v}\\\\&=-\frac{(v+1)^2-2}{1+v}\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

How should I proceed further...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you hear about separation of variables? Get all terms with X on one side an all with v on the other. Then integrate.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Rearrange your terms

$$ y\:dy - x\:dx + y\:dx + x\:dy = d\left(\frac{y^2-x^2}{2}\right)+d(xy) = 0$$

$$\implies y^2-x^2+2xy = C$$

Plug in your initial conditions to solve for C then you can check the answer choices for the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

My usual process is to start by multiplying everything through.  Then, if there is something that mixes different variables/differentials, I try basic strategies such as the product rule (for addition), the quotient rule (for subtraction), or integrating factors.  This solves most of them.  Here, you have:

$$ y\, dx - x\, dx + x\, dy + y\, dy = 0 $$

The mixed ones are $y\,dx$ and $x\,dy$, and they are additive.  So I see if I can use the product rule on them:

$$ (y\, dx + x\, dy) - x\, dx + y\, dy = 0 $$
Yep, that looks like the result of a product rule.  I can make that into this:

$$ d(xy) - x\,dx + y\,dy = 0 $$

Now we just integrate both sides:

$$ \int d(xy) - x\,dx + y\,dy = \int 0 $$

Distributing the integral:

$$ \int d(xy) - \int x\,dx + \int y\,dy = \int 0 $$

And the result:

$$ xy - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} = C $$

Now we solve for $C$ where $x = 0$ and $y = 1$:

$$ 0 - 0 + \frac{1^2}{2} = C $$

$$ C = \frac{1}{2} $$

So the final equation is:

$$ xy - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Or, to remove fractions:

$$ 2xy - x^2 + y^2 = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

$$xv'=-\frac{(v+1)^2-2}{1+v}$$
Substitute $u=v+1$:
$$xu'=-\frac{u^2-2}u$$
The DE is separable:
$$\dfrac {udu}{u^2-2}=-\dfrac {dx}x$$
Integrate both sides.
$$\dfrac {d(u^2-2)}{u^2-2}=-\dfrac {2dx}x$$

---

**Another method:**
$$(y-x)dx+(x+y)dy=0$$
$$y-x+(x+y)y'=0$$
Add $x+y$:
$$-2x+(x+y)(y'+1)=0$$
$$-2x+(x+y)(y+x)'=0$$
Integrate:
$$-x^2+\dfrac 12(x+y)^2=c$$
$$-x^2+2xy+y^2=C$$

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to solve the problem is correct. Since you have observed that the differential equation is homogeneous and can be written as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-y/x}{1+y/x}$, the substitution $v:=y/x$ should work. The small detail is that if you proceed down that path, you will eventually encounter some algebraic problems that need to be resolved. Let's try to work from your initial idea.

So you have noticed that you need to solve $ x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1-2v-v^{2}}{1+v}$, which can be rewritten, with a slight abuse of notation, as $\frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^{2}}dv=\frac{1}{x}dx$. Integrating both sides, we have $ \int\frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^{2}}dv=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{t}dt=-\frac{1}{2}\ln|t|+C=-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-2v-v^{2}|+C$. Therefore, the general solution is $-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-2v-v^{2}|=\ln|x|+C$. Here is where it becomes slightly tedious because although we can switch from $\log$ to $\exp$ in order to seek an explicit solution, we can write $v_{\pm}=-1\pm\frac{e^{-2C}\sqrt{e^{2C}(2e^{2C}x^{2}-1)}}{x}$ but $v=y/x$ and so $ y_{\pm}=xv_{\pm}=x\left(-1\pm\frac{e^{-2C}\sqrt{e^{2C}(2e^{2C}x^{2}-1)}}{x}\right)$ is the general explicit solution.

However, we still need to adjust the initial condition $y(0)=1$, and that's where the real complication arises. So, this approach does not lead (at least initially) to anything useful. Therefore, we need to try another approach. That's why it's good to check if the differential equation is separable or exact before resorting to substitutions. In this case, the differential equation is exact.

*Solving $(y-x)dx+(x+y)dy=0$ with $y(0)=1$ as exact equation*.

Letting $M=-x+y$ and $N=x+y$ then $M_{y}=N_{x}$ give an exact equation. So we can use the standard method: suppose $f(x,y)=C$ is the solution, then $f_{x}=M$ and $f_{y}=N$. Then integrating for example $f_{x}$ respect to $x$ we have $f=\int (-x+y)dx=-x^{2}/2+xy+\phi(y)$ with $\phi$ arbitrary function of $y$. Now differentiation of $f$ respect to $y$ give $f_{y}=x+\phi'(y)$. But $f_{y}=N$ and so $x+\phi'(y)=x+y$. This implies $\phi'(y)=y$ and so $\phi(y)=y^{2}/2$. Hence the general solution is $f(x,y)=C$ that is $-x^{2}/2+y^{2}/2+yx=C$. Setting $y(0)=1$ we get $C=1/2$. Therefore particular solution $y(x)=-x+\sqrt{1+2x^{2}}$.

Finally notice that if $x=2$ then $y=-2+\sqrt{1+2(2)^{2}}=-2+\sqrt{9}=1$ so a point along the solution is $(2,1)$.